# Partially bordered table of Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Use `<table class="table table-bordered">` will create a fully bordered table. But I want to have a table with outer border and a border between rows. It should not have border between columns.

I can solve this problem with `<table class="table" style="border:1px solid #ddd">`. But I'm wondering, if there is a correct bootstrap style class to do that.

**Update #1**: As it seems BS3 does not provide a native style to do that, I've created a pull request to BS3 project. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15790

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a specific class for outside borders only in Bootstrap, the solution you have now is what I would recommend using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend bootstrap with your own class:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-bordered-rows">
```

CSS:

```
.table-bordered-rows td + td { border-left: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything in bootstrap for specifically adding borders. For what it's worth, I created border helpers for my application. The CSS is like so:

```
/* generic border helpers */
.border-b,.border-t,.border-l,.border-r,.border-tb,.border-lr,.border-all{border-style:solid;border-color:#dddddd; border-width:0;}
.border-t,.border-tb,.border-all{border-top-width:1px;}
.border-b,.border-tb,.border-all{border-bottom-width:1px;}
.border-l,.border-lr,.border-all{border-left-width:1px;}
.border-r,.border-lr,.border-all{border-right-width:1px;}
```

- .border-b = border bottom side
- .border-t = border top side
- .border-l = border left side
- .border-r = border right side
- .border-tb = border top and bottom sides
- .border-lr = border left and right sides
- .border-all = border all sides

HTH,

-Ted